# How to dereference environment variables read from file?

Tags: bash, variables, escaping, rsync

Let's say I have a file fi.le:

```
$GNUPG_HOME
$XDG_CONFIG_HOME
$XDG_DATA_HOME
```

In my backup script I'd like to *actually dereference* these variables (in rsync via `--include-from=fi.le`)

That is, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, should become `/home/user/.config`.

I did a loop to check:

```
while read i; do ls "$i"; done < fi.le
```

or

```
for i in `cat fi.le`; do ls $i; done
```

It would return:

> ls: cannot access '$XDG_DATA_HOME': No such file or directory

I suppose that it treats '$' as '\$' (escaped). How do I alter this?

Comment: Is every line just a variable name, or can it be mixed with literal text?

Comment: They're not treated as being escaped, they're just treated data rather than as shell syntax. Or, to put it another way, escaping a `$` will prevent it from being interpreted in a context where it'd normally introduce a variable substitution, but data read from a file isn't one of those contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`envsubst` is your friend:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ cat > vars.txt <<'EOF'
> $HOME
> $USER
> EOF
$ envsubst < vars.txt 
/home/username
username
```

Comment: Did the job perfectly. The handy thing is that the file can consist of other arbitrary strings such as absolute paths and comments (in case of rsync backup script).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `$` at the beginning and then use an indirect variable.

```
while read i; do
    i=${i/\$/} # remove $
    ls "${!i}" # use `$i` as the name of a variable
done < fi.le
```

Answer (score 0):

If fi.le contains only environment variables, then :

```
while read i; do ls "$i"; done < <(envsubst < fi.le)
```